# Bitcoin core libbitcoin_server_a-httpserver.o Error

Tags: c++, bitcoin

I'm trying to install a custom fork of bitcoin core from [HERE](https://github.com/TechMiX/SimorghCoin) And when compiling, I get the following error:

I have installed all the prerequisites i think

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src'
  CXX      bitcoind-bitcoind.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-addrdb.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-addrman.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-bloom.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-blockencodings.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-blockfilter.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-chain.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-checkpoints.o
  CXX      consensus/libbitcoin_server_a-tx_verify.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-httprpc.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-httpserver.o
httpserver.cpp:74:10: error: ‘deque’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   74 |     std::deque<std::unique_ptr<WorkItem>> queue;
      |          ^~~~~
httpserver.cpp:33:1: note: ‘std::deque’ is defined in header ‘<deque>’; did you forget to ‘#include <deque>’?
   32 | #include <support/events.h>
  +++ |+#include <deque>
   33 | 
httpserver.cpp: In member function ‘bool WorkQueue<WorkItem>::Enqueue(WorkItem*)’:
httpserver.cpp:92:13: error: ‘queue’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Enqueue’?
   92 |         if (queue.size() >= maxDepth) {
      |             ^~~~~
      |             Enqueue
httpserver.cpp:95:9: error: ‘queue’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Enqueue’?
   95 |         queue.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<WorkItem>(item));
      |         ^~~~~
      |         Enqueue
httpserver.cpp: In member function ‘void WorkQueue<WorkItem>::Run()’:
httpserver.cpp:106:35: error: ‘queue’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Enqueue’?
  106 |                 while (running && queue.empty())
      |                                   ^~~~~
      |                                   Enqueue
httpserver.cpp:110:31: error: ‘queue’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Enqueue’?
  110 |                 i = std::move(queue.front());
      |                               ^~~~~
      |                               Enqueue
make[2]: *** [Makefile:6520: libbitcoin_server_a-httpserver.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:10888: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src'
make: *** [Makefile:774: all-recursive] Error 1
```

and this is my configuration:

```
Options used to compile and link:
  with wallet   = yes
  with gui / qt = no
  with zmq      = yes
  with test     = yes
  with bench    = yes
  with upnp     = auto
  use asm       = yes
  sanitizers    = 
  debug enabled = no
  gprof enabled = no
  werror        = no

  target os     = linux
  build os      =
```

My OS is Manjaro 20.0.3 Lysia and i use gcc (GCC) 10.1.0.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like a missing include for `deque` https://wandbox.org/permlink/RvGKBapHoSHGm2Vl

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for your answer but i don't know where is this file

Comment: `/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src/httpserver.cpp` line 74 col 10

Comment: You should read the error message. It says: _note: ‘std::deque’ is defined in header ‘<deque>’; did you forget to ‘#include <deque>’?_ It even gives you a recommendation how to fix the problem: _+++ |+#include <deque>_

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for your help i found file and fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include for `deque` is missing in `/home/muhammad/Programs/SimorghCoin/src/httpserver.cpp`. You can add a line

```
#include <deque>
```

after line 32.